VM options for modern JVMs and JDKs
I can't find page with all VM arguments and options for modern JDK, maybe i'm looking bad.
I try to find all VM arguments and options for JDK 21 and only get this page https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/vmoptions-jsp.html. But it is only for JDK under 7 and has a lot of depreacted options. Perhaps someone knows where I can conveniently view all the arguments.

Try viewing under the categories of Oracle docs or the parent directory

Found, thx a lot
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html

check the documentation of  The java Command -- 10 Seconds too late :- )

Also very useful: Java Almanac

The vote to close for "not being about programming" is incorrect. Stack Overflow policy evolved to allow questions on documentation for programming tools.

When you use the command java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal, you’ll see a list of all flags and their effective current value of the current JVM.

See a data base of options at foojay.io. Pretty presentation, but limited to Java 6 through Java 21 as of 2024-05.

Data sourced from ChrisWhoCodes.com. The foojay.io site is prettier, while this site is fresher and more database-y with query options. Java 6 through 23 as of 2024-05.

java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -version

for example, to see a pretty big list of them (not sure what you might do with those, though)
